# How can I add a "data-pin-nopin" the featured image html?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I really want to prevent my featured images from being pinned. It seems so simple but I just don't have the knowledge to do it apprently.

I found this but it doesn't work. I have divi theme if that matters.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', function( $html ){
  if ( false !== stripos( $html, 'data-pin-nopin' ) ) {
    return $html;
  }
  // Add 'data-pin-nopin' to the HTML tag.
  $html = str_replace( '<img ', '<img data-pin-nopin="true" ', $html );
  return $html;
});
```

Comment: I don't know Divi but I'd assume this happens via CSS, no? Where do you have the suggestion from to set `data-pin-nopin`?

Comment: It's the recommended way to prevent someone from pinning an image to pinterest. It has to be added to the image html. Except I cant seem to access that for the featured images.

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit your themes `header.php` and place the following snippet between the `<head></head>` tags to prevent pinning globally.

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" />
```

Alternatively you can use the [Pinterest Block](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pinterest-block/) plugin from which offers you more fine-grained control, also for single posts.

> This plugin allows you to block selected posts and pages from getting
>   pinned on Pinterest.
>
> #### Pinterest Block Features
>
> - Blocks pages by inserting the official meta tag from Pinterest. Learn more
> - Block specified page types: blog home page, front page, posts, pages, archives.
> - Block selected posts and pages.

Comment: That turns off pinning for all images and I dont want that. Only the featured images. I still want my pin images pinnable. I'm trying to avoid adding another plugin since this really shouldnt be hard to do with code. Obviously the plugin puts in the code somehow.

Comment: That plugin won't work either because I just need this one type of image blocked. Not whole pages or posts.

Comment: @ErinandPhillipSantangelo – I see. Unfortunately Divi is premium, so I'm unable to simply check it out myself. But since it's premium you should ask the vendor how they implemented the featured image and how you'd be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'll reach out to them.